# Converting and/or trees to strategy tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, logic, logical-operators, game-theory

I am trying to convert and/or trees I generated to strategy trees (I am not sure if that's a thing but I will explain what I mean). I am having a hard time figuring out what goes where. Here is what I understood and mean by and/or trees:

### And/Or Trees

Trees in the form of limited logical expressions. Operators allowed are **and** and **or**. And other then the two operators we have simple values or operands. So an example expression would be:

```
((a1 and a2) or b1) and (c1 or c2)
```

*(Here I put parenthesis but normally it is handled before creating the tree so I did not count it as an operator etc.)*

So a tree computed by the given expression will be something in form of and's and or's;

```
           and
          /   \
         or    or
        /  \   / \
      and  b1 c1 c2
     /   \ 
   a1    a2
```

But as we know the branchings already means **"or"** and continuation means **"and"**. Here are what I mean by that;

#### And

```
         b1
        /
       b2
      /
     a1
```

is same as saying

```
         b1
        /
      and
      / \
     b2 a1
```

I should clarify that this is in the context of games. So if the player plays to b1, and strategy that follows afterward is b2 then a1, meaning vice versa doesn't matter (both cells must be played on). Correct me if I am wrong at this point as well.

### Strategy Trees

Trees of the second form described above. Just the values are on the tree, as a player would follow the path. (I can't really put the conversion of the tree above as that is kind of the question I am asking, and I still couldn't figure it out). But here is a strategy tree as opposed to the and/or tree above;

```
b1 and ((a1 and a2) or (b2 and (d1 or (c1 or c2))))

                 b1
                /  \
              a1    b2
             /     /  \
            a2    d1  True
                      /  \
                     c1  c2
```

### What Is the Use?

I am using the strategy trees for a two-player game strategy for a player. So the tree does not include second player moves, but only has the first player strategy given by a compact notation. My aim is to see if the given strategy is complete and/or a winning strategy. Basically assume that the first player is going to make a move given by the tree if the cell given is still empty. i.e. a1 and (b1 or c1) means that the first move is to a1. Then the opponent makes a move, and the reply will be either to b1 or c1 depending on where the opponent made his/her move. I might be using an unnecessarily complicated way to solve this, I am open to any other suggestions as well.

Comment: The `True` look redundant. Can't c1 and c2 directly branch from b2?

Comment: @AbhayAravinda In this case you are right, it is redundant. Though if you add a second child to b2, say an 'and' operator. Then ```True``` will be necessary

Comment: Could you give an example for that?

Comment: @AbhayAravinda yeah added. Now that I see, maybe if I make the tree non-binary I think it's okay if I get rid of ```True```.

Comment: Does the min max algorithm solve your problem?

Comment: @AbhayAravinda min/max would work on a two-player strategy, and it's more of a step after creating the tree. So unfortunately not.